# Flutter Provider value is null

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm trying to pass an index from a widget to another through a provider but the value returns by the provider context seems empty.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create:(ctx)=> ProvideIDX(),
    child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Maposm(lieu), //, idcarousel), // Pass index to this class
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                itemCount: lieu.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                  return Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow, child:Text(lieu[index].name));
                },
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                    setState(() {
                      Index(id: index);
                      print(index);
                    });
                  },
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )));
  }
}

class Places {
  String name;
  LatLng coordxy;

  Places({this.name, this.coordxy});
}

class Index {
  int id;
  Index({this.id});
}

class ProvideIDX with ChangeNotifier{
  Index _selectedID;
  set selectedID(id){
    this._selectedID = id;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  get selectedID=>this._selectedID;

}
```

And the provider is called inside Maposm class like this :

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _passIDX= Provider.of<ProvideIDX>(context);
    final  id = _passIDX.selectedID;
    print(id); // show null
```

and the result I got is "null", which of course is not the value I'd like to  use ^^

edit: Even if the code is reduced it appears to be too long for the post. I uploaded the two classes and the yaml on [Gdrive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QkZlMM5mFUpk1OE5ZQDRb0rZw08lox-g?usp=sharing)

Comment: In your code sample, I don't see where `selectedID(id)` is called to "set" the value, so, it should be `null`, (at least on first glance, maybe I'm missing it?).  It's also quite confusing how selectedID isn't an integer, but rather a class that (only) contains an integer, so I would imagine doing a `print(id.id)` would make more sense in your Maposm class usage example instead of `print(id)` which is like asking `print(Index class)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```dart
final _passIDX= Provider.of<ProvideIDX>(context);
```

you should watch your provider:

```dart
final _passIDX = context.watch<ProvideIDX>();
```

Here is a Minimal Working Example:

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => ProvideIDX(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _Child(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () =>
            Provider.of<ProvideIDX>(context, listen: false).increment(),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Child extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _passIDX = context.watch<ProvideIDX>();
    return Text(
      _passIDX.selectedID.toString(),
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96.0),
    );
  }
}

class Places {
  String name;
  Offset coordxy;

  Places({this.name, this.coordxy});
}

class Index {
  int id;
  Index({this.id});

  increment() => id++;

  toString() => id.toString();
}

class ProvideIDX with ChangeNotifier {
  Index _selectedID = Index(id: 0);
  get selectedID => _selectedID;
  set selectedID(id) {
    _selectedID = id;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void increment() {
    _selectedID.increment();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I've modified the code, still got the same result but i see that your calling the provider in the callback, so the pb in my case may come from the way the way i "push" the index value to the provider.

Comment: This too, probably. Can you update your question with a Minimal Working Example? (ideally, with imports, void main() and the rest)

Comment: I've tried but with the import  and main and variable it is to long for stackoverflow. I put the files on my google drive.

Comment: What do you do with `onPageChanged: (index, reason){setState(() {Index(id:index);});},` ?

Comment: By the way, the main reason why it's too long for Stackoverflow is to push new members to simplify the code they provide. It should be a Minimal Working Example. You see, for this case, `flutter_map`, `latlong` and `caousel_slider` are just noise and irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Instead of a setter in your Provider, add a method: `void selectID(int id) { this._selectedID = Index(id: id);notifyListeners(); }`. Then, change your `onPageChanged` callback into `onPageChanged: (index, reason) { Provider.of<ProvideIDX>(context, listen: false).selectID(index);},`

Comment: I use the onPageChanged to pass the value of the carousel Index. Not so sure that flutter_map is irrelevant (i tried to replace with a simple text widget for exemple and i could directly transmit the Index value juste using the callback &setState ) :/

Comment: And a very big thank you !! it's working now.

Comment: Great! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Provider.of(context, listen: false).variableName

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).